# Bottom refresh control for uiscrollview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

How can i add UIRefreshController at the bottom of UIScrollView.
I am implementing load more option in UIScrollView, so that i can load more data into scrollview.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: why don't you use table view ?

Comment: Please look the component [SVPullToRefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh) hope this help

Answer (score 0):

UIRefreshControl can be used only in UITableView as it says in Apples Documentation:

`Because the refresh control is specifically designed for use in a table view that's managed by a table view controller, using it in a different context can result in undefined behaviour.`

Comment: It's better to rethink your design. But if you need it just ``[addSubview:[[UIRefreshControl alloc] init]]```and then add some constraints to it

Answer (score 0):

Put your data into a table view, then this could be easily done using standard `UITableViewDelegate` callbacks. Don't try to manipulate Apple's own UIRefreshControl to go at the bottom of a table or scrollview as it'll end in trouble.

Just do this:

In your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return `data.count+1`

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` check `if (indexPath.row == data.count)`. If so, create and return a basic cell with its text label set to "Load more..."

In your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` check `if (indexPath.row == data.count)` again. If so, trigger your own `[self loadMoreData]` method and then call `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this to handle loading more data in tableview(namely  **dataTable**) :

1) Add an activity indicator(namely **spinner**) at the bottom of the tableview.

2) Do this :

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{

    if(self.dataTable.contentOffset.y<0){
        //it means table view is pulled down like refresh
        return;
    }
    else if(self.dataTable.contentOffset.y >= (self.dataTable.contentSize.height - self.dataTable.bounds.size.height)) {
        NSLog(@"bottom!");
        self.spinner.hidden = false;
        [self.spinner startAnimating];
        [self refreshPulled];
    }

}

-(void)refreshPulled
{
    //get more data and reload table here and hide spinner when all is done

}
```

Hope this helps you.